# Outro Tipo de checkbox

Tags: html

Como que eu poderia fazer uma checkbox que a cada clique nele , seja o mesmo que um valor inserido , assim eu não precise colocar no input ao lado do meu checkbox o número desejado .
Caso eu não tenha sido claro comente , abaixo para me ajudar ao invés de desclassificar minha pergunta.

```html
<tr>
  <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
  <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
  <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja 1l">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
  <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Uma ideia seria usar botões que acrescentem uma variável que é mostrada no text field.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar um exemplo em código ? @mutlei

Comment: Não é muito mais fácil colocar um spinner, ou um botao + e -  em vez de checkbox?

Comment: @Bacco como poderia fazer ? ficaria grato de coloca-se como resposta é que irei usar esse projeto apenas em localhost/tablet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que eu tenha entendido direito, que é alterar o valor só clicando, dá para fazer algo bem prático com JavaScript:

```js
function spin(element,delta,max) {
 var input = element.parentNode.children[1];
 var val = parseInt( '0' + input.value) + delta;
 if(val<0) val = 0;
 if(val>max) val = max;
 input.value = val;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="spin(this,-1,7)">-</button>
  <input name="bacalhau" value="0">
  <button onclick="spin(this,1,7)">+</button>
  Pudim de bacalhau
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="spin(this,-1,10)">-</button>
  <input name="sopa" value="0">
  <button onclick="spin(this,1,10)">+</button>
  Sopa de graviola
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="spin(this,-1,4)">-</button>
  <input name="costela" value="0">
  <button onclick="spin(this,1,4)">+</button>
  Costelinha de polvo
</div>
```

Assim, a pessoa pode tanto digitar, quanto simplesmente clicar no <kbd>-</kbd> e <kbd>+</kbd> para alterar o valor.

A função criada tem 3 parâmetros, o primeiro é o `this` para que a função "saiba" qual foi o ítem clicado, o segundo é quanto acrescentar a cada clique (ou diminuir, se for negativo) e o terceiro é o máximo possível daquele campo, ao clicar o botão.

Se mudar a estrutura do HTML da `div`, basta ajustar o índice em `children[1]` para refletir a posição correta do input.

Isto é um esboço inicial, mas é um bom ponto de partida. Depois pode incrementar com CSS, e melhorar a função para integrar melhor com a validação do HTML5, ou quaisquer customizações necessárias.

Comment: No mysql será inserido , a quantidades e o pedidos né . Obrigado .

Comment: @allanaraujo o input é normal, então você poe os `name` neles de acordo com os campos que desejar

Comment: Costela de polvo tem espinho?

Comment: @bfavaretto Dizem que o cara é invertebrado, mas nunca li sobre ele ser inespinhado.